# Navigation with dynamic width of navigation item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want nav menu with 3 items with links which was very different length of text eg:

home | Very long title | Yes

I want that **width of menu** is 100% but I want that **widht of menu item** is based on text length. (You can do this very easily with table/tr/td tag).

I dont want nav-justified (each item is 33% of width) -> I want that second item is wider since it has more content inside ..

```
<ul class="nav main-categories nav-justified">
    <li>
      <a href="#">title</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Veerryyyy looong title :)</a> // This should be more than 33%
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">title</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this? (I want it to work automatically)

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the width of the item to auto, it will automatically set according to the text in it

```
<style>
    .nav li a{
    width: auto;
    }
    </style>
```